# BIRT - Javascript Math.abs function not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, birt

I have the following data expression in a cell from a table:

```
var abs_number = Math.abs(row["per"]);

if (abs_number >= vars["Tripped"]) {
    'Y (>' + vars["Tripped"] + '%)';
} else {
    'N (<' + vars["Tripped"] + '%)';
}
```

The problem is, if row["per"] == -51.20 and vars["Tripped"] == 4; then this script returns

```
'N (<' + vars["Tripped"] + '%)'
```

Ideally, if the absolute number is > 4, it should return

```
'Y (>' + vars["Tripped"] + '%)';
```

EDIT: The issue was on the way I was setting up the row["per"] variable. Please close or ignore this question. Thanks!

Comment: It returns `'Y (>' + vars["Tripped"] + '%)';`. Just set up the variables yourself and give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

It retuns `'Y (>' + 4 + '%)'`, it works fine, check the snippet

```js
var abs_number = Math.abs(-51.20);

if (abs_number >= 4) {
    console.log('Y (>' + 4 + '%)');
} else {
    console.log('N (<' + 4 + '%)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working. If you plug in your values it does what you want. Do you know for sure that `row["per"]` and `vars["Tripped"]` are returning what you want them to?